# DocusignAPI: UNKNOWN_RECIPIENT

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I have 2 envelope with 2 different document but same recipient information:

My data json below:
Envelope 1:

```
   {
      "envelopeId": "a2c6bb90-bc62-4c54-84f0-47b31ae559ea",
      "uri": "/envelopes/a2c6bb90-bc62-4c54-84f0-47b31ae559ea",
      "statusDateTime": "2017-03-28T06:11:41.9255402Z",
      "status": "sent"
    }
    {
      "templateId": "14c79646-7849-4f15-801e-af85875b9d2a",
      "templateRoles": [
        {
          "email": "nguyenvannhu0405@gmail.com",
          "roleName": "Client",
          "name": "Nguyen Nhu",
          "clientUserId": "1091",
        },
        {
          "email": "nguyenvannhu.1234@gmail.com",
          "roleName": "Signer2",
          "name": "Nguyen Nhu 2",
          "clientUserId": "1092",
          "tabs": {
          }
        }
      ],
      "status": "sent",
      "emailSubject": "Test File Contract.pdf"
    }
```

Envelope 2:

```
{
  "envelopeId": "e0cb2849-7f5c-456d-ae95-0372d2d333f2",
  "uri": "/envelopes/e0cb2849-7f5c-456d-ae95-0372d2d333f2",
  "statusDateTime": "2017-03-28T06:17:39.0928408Z",
  "status": "sent"
}
{
  "templateId": "1080a8a2-d5be-4402-99f7-cbab35910d8d",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "nguyenvannhu0405@gmail.com",
      "roleName": "Client",
      "name": "Nguyen Nhu",
      "clientUserId": "1091",
      "tabs": {

      }
    },
    {
      "email": "nguyenvannhu.1234@gmail.com",
      "roleName": "Signer2",
      "name": "Nguyen Nhu 2",
      "clientUserId": "1092",
      "tabs": {

  "status": "sent",
  "emailSubject": "Test File.pdf"
}
```

Problem is When Client sign in URL, I change Client name(Nguyen Nhu to Nguyen Nhu 12). I sign normal for envelope 1 and envelope 2.

[Envelope 1 is completed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzWBP.png)

But when Co-Client also do the same:change Signer2 name(Nguyen Nhu 2 to Nguyen Nhu 22).

I only sign for envelope 1 and envelope 2 get error:

```
DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: Error calling CreateRecipientView: {
  "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT",
  "message": "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope."
}
   at DocuSign.eSign.Api.EnvelopesApi.CreateRecipientViewWithHttpInfo(String accountId, String envelopeId, RecipientViewRequest recipientViewRequest)
   at DocuSign.eSign.Api.EnvelopesApi.CreateRecipientView(String accountId, String envelopeId, RecipientViewRequest recipientViewRequest)
   at Docusigndll.Docusign.GetUrlDocumentSign(String accountId, String envelopeId, Recipient recipient, String urlRedirect) in d:\soft\Docusigndll\Docusigndll\Docusign.cs:line 269
```

I vaguely think error is because CliendUserId is the same in envelope 1 and envelope 2 when I change name of Co-Client(sign in envelope 1) and Docusign save in database new name of Co-Client.In envelope 2 old name of Co-Client are difference from Name of Recipient save in database of Docusign. => Error.But why Client name I also do the same it isn't get error.

Hope everybody help me
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Once you send an envelope and you are ready to generate a signing URL you need to correctly identify the recipient who will sign using their:

- Recipient Name
- Recipient Email
- ClientUserId
- RecipientId

If any one of these are incorrect then the platform will not be able to identify the recipient and you will receive the `UNKNOWN_RECIPIENT` error you're seeing.

To verify the information that's being set you should do a `GET` request on the envelope recipients after it's been sent but before you attempt to generate the recipient signing URL.  You can use the [EnvelopeRecipients: list](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/) API for that.

Looking at your question it looks like you are changing the recipient name after the envelope is sent but before you create the signing URL?  If that's the case then you may need to do a proper envelope correction to update the recipient information in the envelope, THEN make your signing URL request with the updated info and it should work.

For info on how to make an envelope correction see the [envelopeViews: createCorrect](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createCorrect/) API request.

And for general info on the Embedded Signing API flow see the [Embedding DocuSign](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign) features page.